# Why does nth-of-type() and nth-child() break with unrelated element

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I am obviously missing something really fundamental but I have the following html

```
<div class="test-cont">

    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and am using the following selectors

```
 .test-cont .row:nth-of-type(odd) {
     background: purple;
 }
 .test-cont .row:nth-of-type(even) {
     background: red;
 }
```

Which I believe expresses 'select the `nth child` items of `.text-cont` where class contains `.row` and is either odd or even'.

Yet the `<div class="md-margin"></div>` break these selectors.

So I end up with

[image]

Instead of the alternating pattern I expect. The problem is resolved when I remove the `md-margin` divs. What am I missing?

Comment: The `:nth-of-type` can't be used with classes, it refers to the type of the element `(div,p,li..)`

Answer (score 1):

it is because you have those `md-margin` divs in between, making them the `even` ones.

(althought `:nth-of-type` will show the result you want when using classes - depending on the markup -, but it refers to the element type, that's why `div` with `md-margin` are "counting" here.

### snippet with `md-margin`

```css
.test-cont .row:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
     background: purple;
 }
 .test-cont .row:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
     background: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="test-cont">

    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-margin"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Snippet without `md-margin`

```css
.test-cont .row:nth-of-type(odd)  {
  background: purple;
}
.test-cont .row:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">TEST2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">HELLO WORLD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not know about the downvote, but performance-wise the first pseudo-selector should be removed. `.test-cont .row {  background: purple; }` suffices.

Comment: I get that, but I was trying to explain to the OP his problem in first hand then giving him a way of fixing it, not even thinking of performance, but yes performance wise would be better just use a class to color all of then then afterwards having a selector to just color the desired ones.